# how to format label on PolarArea chart.js vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I've got vue chartjs setup and **I want to format label/show `95.7%`** instead of raw `0.957` as in the screenshot. Same setup I try here works for `Line` chart, but can't make it work in `PolarArea`.

```
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "vue-chartjs": "^5.2.0",
```

[image]

```js
    polarOptions() {
      return {
        plugins: {
          // tried a plugin, no luck..
          labels: {
            type: "percentage",
            render: "percentage",
            fontColor: ["green", "white", "red"],
            precision: 2,
          },
        },

        // tried this extra, no luck
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem: any) {
              return tooltipItem.rLabel.toFixed(0);
            },
          },
        },

        scales: {
          r: {
            ticks: {  
              // exactly this works just fine on Line chart, but not here
              callback: (value: number) => `${(value * 100).toFixed()}%`,
              format: {
                style: "percent",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      };
    },
```

Comment: The `r` scale ticks `callback` seems to work fine, what are you expecting for the tick labels? The tooltip should be configured under `plugins` and its entry there should be `tooltip` (see [tooltip configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip)), not `tooltips`. The plugin currently used to add data labels over the pie chart is [datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/). If you added  a working example, there would be a precise and tested answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `plugins.tooltip.callbacks.label` seems to do the job.

I don't like the way it looks, so happy to see if there's smoother way to do it

```js
    polarOptions() {
      return {
        plugins: {
          tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
              label(context: any) {
                const value = (context.raw * 100).toFixed(1);
                return `${context.dataset.label}: ${value}%`;
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ...
```